# Database structure for simple CMS

Tags: sql, database, content-management-system

I am planning to build a very simple CMS. The requirement is that I must have a database with three tables that have relationships to each other.

I can only think of one table. The table that stores the pages with a title, content, and some other things. But the other two tables, what could it be?

Comment: Planning to build, with preset requirements? Please add the homework tag.

Comment: Maybe one for authors (members), and the second one for news. It's strange that you HAVE to use 3 tables. Is that homework?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you are going to get any many variations as answer.

However, try
article, category and author.